# Is what's a vector and covector subjective?

Tags: dual-spaces

From what I understand, if you have $v \cdot w$ (or in general $v\otimes w=k$ where k is an element of a field), then either v dot *or* dot w can be considered as a linear functional and therefore a covector, and the other a vector. I've heard of a vector itself being called a convector, as if it is because of its contstruction or something.

Comment: In terms of vector *fields* on manifolds, it's not subjective - vector fields come from the tangent bundle (so vectors are first-order infinitesimal paths, in some sense) while covectors come from the dual, the cotangent bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Subjective" is not quite the right word, but it is *relative*.

That is, it makes only makes sense to talk about whether something "is" a vector, or covector, or more general [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor), **with respect to** a base vector space $V$ which (by definition) we take to be the "vectors." Then covectors, or more precisely covectors with respect to $V$, are elements of the [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) vector space $V^{\ast}$ and so forth. But it is equally true to say that the elements of $V$ are covectors with respect to $V^{\ast}$.